# Calculating factorials in Java and printing the steps

Tags: java

The following Java code calculates the factorial of a given number and also prints the intermediate steps.

```
public class Factorial {
   public static int getFactorial(int number) {
     int n = number;
     int factorial = 1;

     while(n > 1) {
       factorial *= n;
       n--;

       System.out.println(factorial + " * " + n + " = " + factorial);
     }

    return factorial;
   }
}
```

When the method is called:

```
Factorial.getFactorial(4);
```

Should print to the console something like the following:

```
4 * 3 = 12
12 * 2 = 24
24 * 1 = 24
```

But instead it prints something like the following:

```
4 * 3 = 4
12 * 2 = 12
24 * 1 = 24
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perfect case to use the *debugger*!! Go ahead, gold opportunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is happening because you're printing the `factorial` variable only. Replace:

```
System.out.println(factorial + " * " + n + " = " + factorial);
```

with:

```
System.out.println(factorial + " * " + n + " = " + factorial * n);
```

Comment: Thanks you. I very much appreciate it.